# SQL Query - Multiple counts on multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

Say there is a simple table named "Table1" with just one column "responseTime" of integer type.
I am looking to get the count of rows with value of "responseTime" less than 10,  count of rows less than 50 and count of rows less than 100, in a single query.

I need to run this in Sybase and MySql.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(responseTime < 10),
    SUM(responseTime >= 10 AND responseTime < 50),
    SUM(responseTime >= 50 AND responseTime < 100)
FROM Table1
```

After @L.Scott Johnson comment, I am not sure what is your goal. So here is another approach if you need double counted records:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(responseTime < 10),
    SUM(responseTime < 50),
    SUM(responseTime < 100)
FROM Table1
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking to double-count the <50 values and triple-count the <10 values, so you can simply your inner logic in the SUM() calls.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson OP can modify this query very easily, it is self explicit. Whatever conditions he needs.

Answer (score 0):

IF OP wanted 3 seperated rows rather than fields, each containing the count, one could just use UNION

```
SELECT count(*) WHERE responseTime < 10
UNION
SELECT count(*) WHERE responseTime <= 10 AND responseTime < 50
UNION
SELECT count(*) WHERE responseTime >= 50 AND responseTime < 100
```

This will return 3 separated rows with the respective *count* in each row.

It is unclear if OP wants a separated result **set** or a single **result**

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
SELECT 
 SUM(IF(responseTime<10,1,0)) as data1,
 SUM(IF(responseTime<=10 AND responseTime<50,1,0)) as data 2,
 SUM(IF(responseTime<100,1,0)) as data3
FROM table1
WHERE ...
```